# How do I get get the value of a cell & store into variable with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with latitude and longitude stored.

I am doing a for loop where I need to take the values of the current row contained within each and store as variables I can then use to do some geocoding work with.

If I do something like:

```
for r in df:
latitude = df['latitude']
```

This returns the latitude WITH the index. How do I just get the value without the index so I can do the work I need within the loop?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you're using that does *not* include how to do this?

Comment: I don't get the posted code. `for r in df:` is the first line, but then `r` isn't used anywhere else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following should work:

```
latitude = latitude.values[0]
```

`.values` accesses the numpy representation of a `pandas.DataFrame`
Assuming your code `latitude = df['latitude']` really results in a DataFrame of shape `(1,1)`, then the above should work.

Comment: Simple but I seriously couldn't find when searching for an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Yes, pandas does not really encourage working this way. Most of the time it's easier and faster to use apply when you cannot easily vectorize your code with pandas functions.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It's funny because once I got your answer and started doing some more research I then realized I was going about this wrong but without it I wouldn't have gone down that road. So it was definitely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
                   {'First':'Bill'
                    ,'Last':'Thompson'
                    ,'AcctNum':'0001'
                   ,'AcctValue':100},
                   {'First':'James'
                    ,'Last':'Winters'
                    ,'AcctNum':'0002'
                    ,'AcctValue':200},
                   {'First':'Anna'
                    ,'Last':'Steele'
                    ,'AcctNum':'0003'
                    ,'AcctValue':300},
                   {'First':'Sean'
                    ,'Last':'Reilly'
                    ,'AcctNum':'0004'
                    ,'AcctValue':400}
                   ])

# Select data and set it to a variable
account_value = df.loc[df['AcctNum'] == '0003']['AcctValue'].values[0]
print account_value
```

Comment: I think you are missing the second `]` for `loc`

Comment: What if I want to do this based on a variable? The row I can name, but the column would be a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like this. This works for me.
DF.iloc[2].Name

Here 2 is the row , and the Name is the column name.
You can do an iteration in while loop after that.

Hope this helps.